# One http request takes 200% CPU

Tags: lighttpd, debian-squeeze

Going to one of my websites produces this;

top;

[image]

Seconds later all goes back to normal again..... do I maybe have some sort of aggressive http logger or something installed?

rcconf;

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with the PHP application running on your server.

Don't ask "which problem". You provide no information so we can't do also.

Comment: If I disable my vhosts one by one, will I reach the one causing issues?

Comment: @natti Only if you can reproduce the load. And even then you only find the culprit, but not the problem.

Comment: There is no load. These websites are all new and receive virtually no visitors whatsoever, yet still this problem occurs right after boot. I aksed this question prior to trying to find a script causing issues, because it may well have been a logging app or something similar I was not aware of. Frankly, I don't understand all of the downvotes. I'll try to zone in on the issue now.

Comment: @natti This is **no** forum where you can drop your problems and wait for discussion or solutions. Ask a concrete question and you will receive answers. Ask a broad question (as you did) and receive downvotes.

Comment: Even after disabling all vhosts, meaning all pages default to the lighttpd placeholder page, the problem still occurs. Which is weird because no PHP scripts can even be reached through any url redirecting to my server's IP.

Comment: @natti So what? I never said that this PHP application was triggered through a web server. You can still run it from command line and cron. End of discussion as this leads to nothing!

Answer (score 3):

How should we know what you have installed? Your package listing tells nothing about what gets executed when you receive an HTTP request.

It's run as a CGI, which is about the slowest method possible to run a script, but beyond that it might just be a really crappy PHP script or something that is inherently resource-hungry. Or one of countless other potential problems.

Comment: I provied a sreenshot of my rcconf in hopes someone would simply spot some logging utility that eats alot of memory, but I had to post it as a link because of < 10 rep... sorry. It made sense to me because the problem occurs right after booting the server.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you think some kind of logging utility could be the most likely problem in your case. HTTP requests spawn a CGI process running a PHP script. This process consumes a lot of resources, which suggests your problem are likely your PHP scripts.

Comment: I didn't know this website is for people with a minimum amount of experience under their belt. I did not know a logging application could not produce this problem, for all I knew such an application could in fact increase a php-cgi's script memory usage.

Comment: Well, normally logging is done by Apache and it takes very few resources. Additional logging could be done by your PHP scripts, but if this takes any amount of time we are back at square one: crappy PHP. But you don't even tell us what kind of PHP scripts are running on your server: Something self-written? A CMS or blog software? Anyway, if you read our [faq], you will notice that this site is for professionals.